# Prevent dynamic owl:import in Jena OntModel

Tags: import, rdf, owl, jena

I'm trying to read an owl file in jena.
I would like related owl files specified by the property `owl:import` not being automatically imported.
Is that possible ?

I'm reading the model like this:

```
OntModel onto = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
onto.read(rdfURL);
```

with rdfURL being `"https://<mymodel>.owl"`

Here triples importing other owl files:

```
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/cp/owl/agentrole.owl">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/cp/owl/agentrole.owl">
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/cp/owl/objectrole.owl"/>
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/schemas/cpannotationschema.owl"/>
  </owl:Ontology>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The reason for this is that i don't want Classes and Properties defined in imported models to be in the result of queries against the read one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different way that may work here:

1 - Control imports via the OntModel document manager:

`onto.getDocumentManager().setProcessImports(false);`

before reading into the model.

2 - Depending on what information to make visible, it might be more useful to modify the data: read into a plain RDF model, remove the imports statements and then put into an OntModel.